# Apple Battery Charger - does not charge to 100%?

Tags: battery

I have recently purchased the [Apple Battery Charger](http://store.apple.com/au/product/MC500X/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY) and immediately charged the batteries that came with it. A few days later (3 or 4) I placed the batteries into my mouse and noticed that they only indicate about 75% full. Is this correct? Is the value being read wrong (they are actually 100% full) or do they not fully charge?

Comment: The reviews on the apple site seem to mirror my experience: http://store.apple.com/au/reviews/MC500X/A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s hard to tell with this new product, that is really a normal battery charger. Rechargeable batteries should charge all the way to 100% especially when they are new. If you’re not getting a full charge, try depleting them all and fully charge them, see if that works. Otherwise, batteries may be defective or it could be a mouse/software misinterpretation.